# How to add User Defined Exception for JUnit (expected) tag

Tags: spring, junit4

I just want to know how to add userdefined exception for Test method of Junit.

for instance, we put exception as

```
@Test (expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testMethod()
{
}
```

instead of that, can we specify our new user defined exception like,

```
@Test (expected = MyException.class)
public void testMethod()
{

}
```

where MyException.java includes :

```
public class MyException extends NullPointerException
{

}
```

Comment: Erm, have you tried it??

Comment: Yaa. It worked out. sorry my testmethod was generating another exception. so it did not worked at first